# Create link list from text file

Tags: c, malloc, singly-linked-list

Having trouble reading in text file and storing it within a linked list. I am reading in a file that has first name, l name, priority, and reading level. I believe the issue could either be that I am not properly mallocing the strings/tempPtr, or that my loop is continually running. When running the program, it is continually running, no seg faults.

```
typedef struct Student{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    int priority;
    int readingLevel;
    bookIds* wishlist;
    struct Student* next;
}student;    

student* buildStudentList(char* studentsFile, student* head)
{
    int i;
    FILE* fp;
    student* tempPtr = NULL;
    if((fp = fopen(studentsFile, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file\n");
            return 0;
        }

    student* current = NULL;
    tempPtr = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
    tempPtr->firstName = malloc(sizeof(char)* NAME);
    tempPtr->lastName = malloc(sizeof(char)* NAME);

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %d",tempPtr->firstName, tempPtr->lastName, tempPtr->priority, tempPtr->readingLevel) != EOF)
        {
            tempPtr->next = NULL;
            if(head == NULL)
                {
                    head = tempPtr;
                    current = tempPtr;
                    tempPtr = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
                }
            else
                {
                    current->next = tempPtr;
                    current = tempPtr;
                    tempPtr = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
                }
        }
    free(tempPtr);
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out exactly where the program is looping and what the linked list looks like at that point. That's the right way to debug such small programs. Only turn to Stackoverflow after you have exhausted all avenues of debugging on your own.

Comment: Turn on full compiler warnings. You have problems in your `fscanf()` call, it should be `&tempPtr->priority` and `&tempPtr->readingLevel`

Comment: You need to allocate space for `tempPtr->firstName` and `tempPtr->lastName` every time you allocate another `student`. Maybe you should just declare these as arrays in the structure instead of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the `student` structure so that `firstName` and `lastName` are arrays rather than pointers. There's no need to use dynamic allocation when they're always the same size.

```
typedef struct Student{
    char firstName[NAME];
    char lastName[NAME];
    int priority;
    int readingLevel;
    bookIds* wishlist;
    struct Student* next;
}student;
```

Next, whenever you allocate a new `student`, you need to initialize the `wishList` and `next` pointers to `NULL`.

When you call `fscanf()`, you need to pass pointers to the `int` members that you're filling in.

You can simplify your code by doing the `malloc()` in just one place, rather than before the loop and then repeating it in each branch of the `if`. Read the input into local variables, then allocate the `student` once that has succeeded.

```
typedef struct Student{
    char firstName[NAME];
    char lastName[NAME];
    int priority;
    int readingLevel;
    bookIds* wishlist;
    struct Student* next;
}student;    

student* buildStudentList(char* studentsFile, student* head)
{
    int i;
    FILE* fp;
    if((fp = fopen(studentsFile, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file\n");
            return 0;
        }

    student* current = NULL;

    char firstName[NAME], lastName[NAME];
    int priority, readingLevel;

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %d",firstName, lastName, &priority, &readingLevel) != EOF)
        {
            student* tempPtr = malloc(sizeof(student));
            tempPtr->next = NULL;
            tempPtr->wishlist = NULL;
            strcpy(tempPtr->firstName, firstName);
            strcpy(tempPtr->lastName, lastName);
            tempPtr->priority = priority;
            tempPtr->readingLevel = readingLevel;

            if(head == NULL)
                {
                    head = tempPtr;
                }
            else
                {
                    current->next = tempPtr;
                }
            current = tempPtr;
        }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: ok so now when I call this function in main I am seg faulting. I ran through line by line in the function which doesn't seem to be having issues. In main I have it as head = buildStudentList(student, head). Where head = NULL and student is of char type set to argv[1].

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine. Maybe you have a problem somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Ok so this is how it is called in main. Not too sure where I could get this seg fault issue. Ran GDB but does not seem to be showing exactly the source of the seg fault. int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        if (argc < 1 || argc > 4)
        {
                printf("INVALID USE OF PROGRAM\n");
                return 0;
        }
        char* file = argv[1];
        //char* wishlist = argv[2];

         student* first = NULL;

        first = buildStudentList(file, first);
        //printStudents(head); 

        return 0;
}

Comment: If I comment out the function I do not get a seg fault issue.

Comment: That doesn't mean the problem is in this function. If you have undefined behavior, it can cause errors in unrelated code.